# Access subclass type from its superclasses function

Tags: swift, class, inheritance

Is there a way to have a function in a superclass, that can (when called through a subclass) access said subclasses type?

I want a universal `info()` in my masterclass that can be called an give information about the type of the subclass.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. The answer depends on the type of information you are hoping to discover, but if it is class reflection you are after you might find NSStringFromClass and NSClassFromString provide what you want.  Otherwise you could return a Dictionary of properties your class exposes.  It is a little difficult to answer without a clearer idea of what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want, but `self` always returns the currently instantiated class - see below

```
class A {
    init() { }

    func whatClassAmI() -> String {
        return "\(type(of: self))"
    }
}

class B: A { }

let a = A()
let sa = a.whatClassAmI() // "A", of course

let b = B()
let sb = b.whatClassAmI() // "B", as required
```